# C++, Wondering why making this var static makes it passable to my function

Tags: c++

I apologize for the odd description.

```
class test {
public:
    const int x = 10;
    int func(int arr[][x], int size);
private:
};
```

the above is not allowed. However, what I have below is totally fine. What does making it static change?

```
class test {
public:
    static const int x = 10;
    int func(int arr[][x], int size);
private:
};
```

Comment: In general in the first case just because `x` is a `const int` doesn't mean it's known at compile time. You've provided a default value for it, but you could still for instance add a `test(int y) : x(y) { }` constructor and have an instance of `test` with a different value of `x`. However a `static const int` does in fact always have the same value across all instances no matter what else you write in the body of the class, so it can be used as a constant expression for an array size.

Comment: Wow I had no idea a constructor could change a const value like that. Thank you so much

Comment: @Quinton it’s not changing it, it’s setting it.

Comment: I guess I would have assumed that my setting it as a const = 10 could not be changed, even by a constructor. I never knew that was possible.

Comment: Essentially it's saying "here's what to set `x` to _if a constructor doesn't specify otherwise_" instead of "here's what to set `x` to". I agree it's a bit surprising.

Comment: Wow. That's awesome. Makes total sense. Thanks for the help!